# Crosscompile libdaemon to ARM does not work?

Tags: arm, cross-compiling

I tried to cross-compile the library  [libdaemon](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/libdaemon/) for an ARM architecture but I'm facing the problem that libdeamon is not being cross-compiled, and I cannot understand why. After cross-compiling (make the ./conf and make install) the library libdeamon, I have been able to check the library isn't crosscompiled for arm,since it's been "crosscomppiled" for the build a intel as it can be seen

```
:~/libdaemon-0.14$ file -F usr/*/*.*
    usr/lib/libdaemon.lausr/lib/libdaemon.a       libtool library file,
    usr/lib/libdaemon.sousr/lib/libdaemon.a       symbolic link to `libdaemon.so.0.5.0'
    usr/lib/libdaemon.so.0usr/lib/libdaemon.a     symbolic link to `libdaemon.so.0.5.0'
    usr/lib/libdaemon.so.0.5.0usr/lib/libdaemon.a ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0xe4959941fb153e1dec5ec84f798dc32928219ae2, not stripped
```

The configure for the libdaemon is this

```
~/libdaemon-0.14$ ./configure --build=i686-linux --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --enable-shared --prefix=/usr
~/libdaemon-0.14$ sudo make DESTDIR=/home/j/libdaemon-0.14 install
```

Any tip of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check the configure log.

Comment: the configure log doesn't show an error further the lynx issue which I've read is normal